# I pip installed Prefect but it says "ModuleNotFoundError": 'No module named 'prefect'

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, scheduled-tasks, python-3.10, prefect

I'm not sure what the issue is but

- I already pip installed prefect and confirmed it's installed: Prefect 2.0
- Using VsCode
- Python 3.10.6

check image below for error and code posted for easy copy pasta

```
from prefect import flow, task
import httpx

@task(retries=3)
def get_stars(repo):
    url = f"https://api.github.com/repos/{repo}"
    count = httpx.get(url).json()["stargazers_count"]
    print(f"{repo} has {count} stars!")

@flow
def github_stars(repos):
    for repo in repos:
        get_stars(repo)

# call the flow!
github_stars(["PrefectHQ/Prefect", "PrefectHQ/prefect-aws",  "PrefectHQ/prefect-dbt"])
```

[image: Prefect Install]

Edit: Found the solution:

[image: Solution found]

Comment: Are you quite sure your VSCode is using the same installation of Python where you installed `prefect`?  Most computers have several Python installations.

Comment: I assume you didn't install the package in a virtual environment, while trying to use it outside of it? Just a thought, that being a common mistake

Comment: I'm pretty sure, I installecd within vscode and only  have one python interpreter installed

Comment: @alexakarpov I beileve it's selected, I'm kinda new to Python.

Comment: @alexakarpov venv img: https://imgur.com/a/D8HPP6v

Comment: @SikehJaphet I don't understand your question.

Comment: Each time you download a module, test it. Try to test **prefect** in a python interactive terminal to see if you downloaded and installed it well. Open your current working directory C:\Users...\testPrefect\ in command prompt. If you are using a virtual environment start the environment and go to (venv) C:\Users...\testPrefect\ in command prompt. After which type python. When python starts, type  `import prefect` to see if it is present and imported successfully.

Comment: This is caused by the use of the virtual environment. Please configure the virtual environment correctly. For details, see [vene](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see that you have not activated your virtualenv that might be the issue, you need to first install virtualenv.

Using this you can install virtualenv in your system:

```
pip install virtualenv
```

then you have to create a virtual environment, you can do that by following command.

```
python -m virtualenv myEnv # ---> whatever name you want here
```

and then you have to activate the environment by following command:

```
myEnv\Scripts\activate
```

and to deactivate, simply use:

```
deactivate
```

Comment: I just used Venv but that might be a better option though I managed to fix it by changing the pyvenv.cfg ->include-system-site-packages = true

Comment: @WilliamJPriest I doubt that's a good fix, nevermind can you please close the question?

Answer (score 0):

Do you happen to use venv for virtual environment management? We've seen some users struggling to set it up with venv. Could you try installing with Conda and report back?

Comment: I do use Venv and I managed to fix it by changing the pyvenv.cfg ->include-system-site-packages = true

Comment: Not still didn't work for me:

`home = C:\Anaconda3
include-system-site-packages = true
version = 3.8.5`